# password syntax checking based on password policy in Liferay

Tags: liferay

I'm implementing a separate Change Password module in Liferay, especifically, extending the Login portlet such that it has a Change Password upon login.

I tried calling the struts action enterprise_admin/edit_user but it does not work but I have implemented my own password checker by getting the Password Policy of that user and checking the minUpperCase, etc in that class but is there a way that i can check the syntax without looping through the password and counting the minUpperCase, etc.?

Does Liferay has a specific method in checking whether the password applies in the password policy?

Answer (score 1):

You could try this. That's what they do in UserLocalService

```
PasswordPolicy passwordPolicy = passwordPolicyLocalService.getDefaultPasswordPolicy(companyId);
PwdToolkitUtil.validate(companyId, 0, password1, password2, passwordPolicy);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't see PwdToolkitUtil you could try this way:

```
Object[] arguments= {user.getCompanyId(), user.getUserId(), password, password, passwordPolicy};
MethodKey methodKey = new MethodKey("com.liferay.portal.security.pwd.PwdToolkitUtil", "validate", long.class, long.class, String.class , String.class, PasswordPolicy.class);
PortalClassInvoker.invoke(false, methodKey, arguments);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only customized the login because of the "change password on login" feature, you could also just use the portal's default behaviour with [`UserLocalServiceUtil.updatePassword`](http://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.1/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/service/UserLocalServiceUtil.html#updatePassword%28long,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20boolean%29), nothe the fourth parameter:

```
public static User updatePassword(long userId,
                                  String password1,
                                  String password2,
                                  boolean passwordReset,
                                  boolean silentUpdate)
                       throws PortalException,
                              SystemException

Updates the user's password, optionally with tracking and validation of the change.

Parameters:
    userId - the primary key of the user
    password1 - the user's new password
    password2 - the user's new password confirmation
    passwordReset - whether the user should be asked to reset their password the next time they login
    silentUpdate - whether the password should be updated without being tracked, or validated. Primarily used for password imports.  
Returns:
    the user  
Throws:
    PortalException - if a user with the primary key could not be found 
    SystemException - if a system exception occurred
```